# HBase Scan Performance

Tags: caching, hadoop, hbase, database-scan

I am performing a range scan that is giving me 500k records.
If I set `scan.setCaching(100000)` it took less than one second, but if `scan.setCaching(100000)` is not set it took nearly 38 sec.

If I set `scan.setBlockCache(false)` and `scan.setCaching(100000)` what will happen? Will the rows be cached or not?

I am dropping OS cache after first scan but there is no change in the time for scanning the records. Why?

Then how can I check the read performance?

Answer (score 22):

`Scan.setCaching` is a misnomer. It should really be called something like `Scan.setPrefetch`. `setCaching` actually specifies how many rows will be transmitted per RPC to the regionserver. If you use `setCaching(1)` then every time you call `next()` you pay the cost of a round-trip to the regionserver. The down side to setting it to a larger number is that you pay for extra memory in the client, and potentially, you are fetching rows that you won't use, for example, if you stop scanning after reaching a certain number of rows or after you've found a specific value.

`Scan.setBlockCache` means something entirely different like Chandra pointed out. It basically instructs the regionserver to not pull any data from this Scan into the HBase BlockCache which is a separate pool of memory from the MemStore. Note that MemStores are used for writing and BlockCache is used for reading, and these two pieces of memory are completely separate. HBase currently does not use the BlockCache as a write-back cache. You can control the size of the block cache with the `hfile.block.cache.size` config setting in `hbase-site.xml`. Similarly you can control the total pool size of the MemStore via the `hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size` setting.

You might want to use `setBlockCache(false)` if you are doing a full table scan, and you don't want to flush your current working set in the block cache. Otherwise, if you are scanning data that is being used frequently, it would probably be better to leave the `setBlockCache` alone.

Comment: Scan.setCaching(HBASECACHING), where `HBASECACHING` specifies the number of rows to cache

Answer (score 6):

Hbase has 2 types of cache structures - `memory store` and `block cache`.
 **memory store is implemented as MemStore and the cache you use for reading is block cache**.
 When a data block is read from HDFS, it is cached in the BlockCache. Subsequent reads of neighboring data are simply served from the BlockCache. 
 So, when you manually set scan.set Block Cache(false) then , **it will stop caching the rows it reads from hdfs.
 scan.set-caching(100000) is a client side optimisation related to scanners. So it will still work unaffected**

Comment: `setCaching` affects client-side behavior while `setBlockCache` affects regionserver-side behavior, so your reasoning for why `setCaching` won't have any effect is incorrect.

Comment: @b4hand , thanks for pointing that I out. I had overlooked that fact. Have a look at my changed answer.