# Spark not be able to retrieve all of Hbase data in specific column

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, hbase

My Hbase table has 30 Million records, each record has the column `raw:sample`, raw is columnfamily sample is column. This column is very big, the size from a few KB to 50MB. When I run the following Spark code, it only can get 40 thousand records but I should get 30 million records:

```
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "10.1.1.15:2181")
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "sampleData")
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS, "raw:sample")
conf.set("hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize","0")
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
var arrRdd:RDD[Map[String,Object]] = hBaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2).map(...)
```

Right now I work around this by get the id list first then iterate the id list to get the column `raw:sample` by pure Hbase java client in Spark foreach. 
Any ideas please why I can not get all of the column `raw:sample` by Spark, is it because the column too big?

A few days ago one of my zookeeper nodes and datanodes down, but I fixed it soon since the replica is 3, is this the reason? Would think if I run `hbck -repair` would help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Internally, TableInputFormat creates a Scan object in order to retrieve the data from HBase.

Try to [create a Scan object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_scan.htm) (without using Spark), configured to retrieve the same column from HBase, see if the error repeats:

```
// Instantiating Configuration class
  Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

  // Instantiating HTable class
  HTable table = new HTable(config, "emp");

  // Instantiating the Scan class
  Scan scan = new Scan();

  // Scanning the required columns
  scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("name"));
  scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("city"));

  // Getting the scan result
  ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);

  // Reading values from scan result
  for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next())

  System.out.println("Found row : " + result);
  //closing the scanner
  scanner.close();
```

In addition, by default, TableInputFormat is configured to request a very small chunk of data from the HBase server (which is bad and causes a large overhead). Set the following to [increase the chunk size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528859/hbase-scan-performance):

```
scan.setBlockCache(false);
scan.setCaching(2000);
```

Comment: I tried everything, but still can not retrieve all of the rows by scan.

Comment: Which rows are not returned? The last ones? Or does it miss rows in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

For a high throughput like yours, Apache Kafka is the best solution to integrate the data flow and keeping data pipeline alive. Please refer http://kafka.apache.org/08/uses.html for some use cases of kafka

One more
http://sites.computer.org/debull/A12june/pipeline.pdf

Comment: The data already in Hbase, you mean I'd better read from Hbase to Kafka and then consume from Kafka? I think it's redundant, it's not necessary use Kafka as a bridge from Hbase and Spark/MR. It's just a batch job using Spark read data from Hbase.

Comment: Kafka is not necessary, but it will ensure the large data pipeline and data flow wont break. For 30 million records, Kafka makes your system more stable.